# Can I load a managed C# DLL from a physical path instead of loading from GAC via CLRProfiler

Tags: clr, profiler, clr-profiling-api

The managed DLL can be loaded when it is in GAC using the public key token and assembly name.

```
MetaDataAssemblyEmit->DefineAssemblyRef(pbPublicKeyOrToken, publicKeySize, assemblyName, &assemblyMetaData, NULL, 0, 0, &mdAssemblyRef);
```

I want to load the DLL reference from a physical path instead of loading from the GAC.

I tried the below code,

```
LoadLibrary(L"C:\Packages\MyDotNetAssembly.dll");
```

The above code loaded the DLL into the process, It is not loading the DLL into the CLR runtime.
So DefineAssemblyRef could not find the DLL. Getting the below error,

> Could not load file or assembly 'MyDotNetAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8b6549a3d401ea66' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I load the managed DLL into the current runtime or app domain, to make it work via C++ code?

Comment: Have you looked into Assembly.LoadFrom and / or one of its variant?

Comment: I can load it via C# code using the Assembly resolve event. But I need this to be implemented in CPP.

Comment: Did you find a solution @anbu2388 ?

Comment: @anbu2388 We need the same. Did you fixed this ?